# Merge rows if they have the same values and take from one column the mean

Tags: r

I' m rather new to programming and this community. Hopefully can one of you help me, because i'm a stuck.

I have a `df` that looks as follows:

```
Time | Location | day | direction | speed

08:00| 143.3    | Mo  |    L      | 120.0

08:00| 143.3    | Mo  |    L      | 110.0

09:00| 143.3    | Mo  |    L      | 120.0

09:00| 143.3    | Mo  |    L      | 100.0

09:00| 143.3    | Mo  |    L      | 110.0

09:00| 143.3    | Mo  |    R      | 121.2
```

I want to merge the rows IF the `Time` and `Location` and `day` and `direction` are the same as another row. If this is all `TRUE`: it should merge and take the `mean` of the speed into a single row.

So it should be looking like this:

```
Time | Location | day | direction | speed

08:00| 143.3    | Mo  |    L      | 115.0

09:00| 143.3    | Mo  |    L      | 110.0

09:00| 143.3    | Mo  |    R      | 121.2
```

Can anyone help me with this?

ps. Sorry for the poor display of the `df`! I will edit this.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plyr)
result = plyr::ddply(df,c("Time","Location","day","direction"),function(x){
  data.frame(speed=mean(x$speed))
})
result
```